# Not receiving all fields in php mail

Tags: php, email, scripting

Here is the mail handler only part being received in sent emails is the actual message missing parts are name and phone.

```
<?php
session_start();

    $email_to = "test@test.com";
    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $subject   = $_POST['subject'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];

    $headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

    if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "success";       
    } 
    else{
        echo "failed";     
    }  
?>
```

Here is the html part which I have checked over and over and cant figure out whats wrong

```
<form id="contact" class="row" name="form1" method="post" action="">

                <div class="span2">
                <label>Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="full" name="name" id="name"/>
                <div id="error_name" class="error">Please check your name</div>
                </div>

                <div class="span2">
                <label>Phone <span class="req">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="full" name="phone" id="phone"/>
                <div id="error_phone" class="error">Please check your phone</div>
                </div>

                <div class="span4">
                <label>Email <span class="req">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="full" name="email" id="email"/>
                <div id="error_email" class="error">Please check your email</div> 
                </div>

                <div class="span8">
                <label>Message <span class="req">*</span></label>
                <textarea cols="8" rows="10" name="message" id="message" class="full"></textarea>
                <div id="error_message" class="error">Please check your message</div>
                <div id="mail_success" class="success"> Thank you. Your message has been sent.</div>
<div id="mail_failed" class="error">Error, email not sent</div>

<p id="btnsubmit"><input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" class="btn btn-large"/></p>               
                </div>              
              </form>
```

Js script -------------------

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function(){
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email  = $("#email").val();
    var message  = $("#message").val();

    var error = false;

    if (name.length == 0) {
        var error = true;
        $("#error_name").fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        $("#error_name").fadeOut(500);
    }

    if (phone.length == 0) {
        var error = true;
        $("#error_phone").fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        $("#error_phone").fadeOut(500);
    }

     if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf("@") == "-1" || email.indexOf(".") == "-1"){
       var error = true;
       $("#error_email").fadeIn(500);
     }
     else {
       $("#error_email").fadeOut(500);
     }

     if(message.length == 0){
        var error = true;
        $("#error_message").fadeIn(500);
     }else{
        $("#error_message").fadeOut(500);
     }

     if(error == false){
       $("#send").attr({"disabled" : "true", "value" : "Loading..." });

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "send.php",    
         data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "Website Enquiry" + "&message=" + message,
         success: function(data){    
          if(data == 'success'){
            $("#btnsubmit").remove();
            $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);
          }else{
            $("#mail_failed").html(data).fadeIn(500);
            $("#send").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "send");
          }     
         }  
       });  
    }
  return false;                      
  });    
});
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$name` or `$phone` - maybe you should concatenate them onto `$message`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your HTML markup. The values should get `POST`ed correctly. Do `print_r($_POST);` -- do you see all the fields and values correctly?

Comment: Look at the variable `$phone` - you set it, and never use it.

Comment: @Paul I fixed your code, take a look and understand how it works.

Comment: Check out the PHP manual on both `mail()` and `headers()` functions on how to concatenate and send Email as HTML, should you want to do that further down the road. [**Click here** to visit PHP.net's functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) @Paul Leaving this as a reference for you.

Comment: As per your edit Paul, in your `data:` you have everything but `phone`. I'm not a JS expert when it comes to scripts like that, I use a standard (one size fits all) Ajax script that I don't need to worry about any additional parameters. @Paul --- See if Salivan can help if my suggestion (in this comment) doesn't help.

Comment: On an added note Paul, if you originally were using JS for your form in the first place, you should have posted it at the same time of your original post, that way it leaves the guesswork out of everything, and people will know exactly how to deal with all the `parts` involved. ;-) Never leave any important/relevant information out of the equation, *as it were*.

Comment: added ---"&phone=" + phone +--- and its all working fine now cant thank you enough guys @Fred-ii- Salivan

Comment: Right on Paul, glad to hear it and you're welcome. Glad I could help (again) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you are missing parts!... You simply declare variables, but you didn't include them in the mail itself.

In this example, I'm adding $name and $phone to $message body.

```
<?php
session_start();

    $email_to = "test@test.com";
    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
    $message  = $_POST['message'] . "\n";
    $message  .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $message  .= "Phone: " . $phone;

    $headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

    if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "success";       
    } 
    else{
        echo "failed";     
    }  
?>
```

Comment: I'll kick myself if this works, just testing it now be bk in 5 thanks

Comment: I suggest you add some spacing and/or new lines to the variables in `$message` otherwise it risks in being all bunched up. I.e.: `Hello, this is my messageFred555-123-4567`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would have left that as an exercise to Paul. but since you mention it...

Comment: Ah, you have a point there ;-) However, it will still be bunched up between name and phone number. I suggest `$message  .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";` or  `$message  .= "Name: " . $name . " ";`

Comment: nope didnt work when added spacing I got this in email test<br/>Name: PaulPhone: this is what was received without adding space  this is a test emailPaul

Comment: @Paul did you get Name:, Phone:?

Comment: it was bunched up like this PaulPhone:

Comment: Replace the `<br />` in `$message  = $_POST['message'] . "<br/>";` with a `\n` --- `$message  = $_POST['message'] . "\n";` I just tested it now. The reason is your headers are not being sent in HTML format. @Paul

Comment: And also what I mentioned in a previous comment. @Paul You need to know/learn how to add spacing with PHP and headers functions => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php `Salivan's` answer works, but you need to put in a little effort ;-) See that link on how to add HTML functionality.

Comment: Thanks Fred just trying that now

Comment: You're welcome @Paul and do accept Salivan's answer by clicking the white checkmark till it turns green. ;-) Cheers and Welcome to [S.O.](http://stackoverflow.com/)!

Comment: I'm curious though, why are you using `session_start();` when you have no referenced `$_SESSION` – For example `$_SESSION['name']="Larry";` ? @Paul

Comment: Fred nearly there im now receiving this --- this is a test email
Name: Paul
Phone: ---Phone field is still blank?

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`

Comment: Any thoughts on why phone field is blank though Fred?

Comment: Just an added note Paul. I noticed what looks to me like an/your actual email address. For future reference, use `$email_to = "email@example.com";` that way, if it is in fact your actual email address, you won't get spammed by people pulling your email from here.

Comment: Phone field was not blank when I tested Salivan's code with your form. @Paul

Comment: Yeah realised id done that changed it further down to test@test.com

Comment: Yet, I suspect it may be because you have `session_start();` and because you did not have `$phone` in the code before, the session is still active. Either comment it out i.e.: `// session_start();` or remove it altogether and try it again. @Paul

Comment: @Paul do +1 on freds comments. He helped you allot! :)

Comment: Plus, my test consisted of `action="email_handler.php"` and you have `action=""` which I take it you are running everything on the same page, which is not always good practice. @Paul `action=""` means "execute on same page".

Comment: Salvian Fred you guys have been awesome I've been stuck on this for two days now, Thanks gonna +1 just now :-)

Comment: You're most welcome, glad we could help. @Paul Enjoy the adventure. ;-)

Comment: When you put your mouse over a comment, you will see an `up arrow`, click on it. @Paul and if ever someone makes a bad comment, you will see a small `flag` under the arrow. Options will popup for you to make a choice as to the `why`.

Comment: Same thing goes for answers and questions. The BIG `up` arrow means UP VOTE (good) which gives added credibility, while the `down` arrows are BAD which means a person either disagreed, or did not like the question/answer. @Paul

Comment: Got that no probs im just not getting anything when mousing over comments

Comment: `FYI` Paul: We can't add too many comments in questions/answers, because they stand at being flagged to be closed, because of being too "chatty". You might have noticed `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?` once this appears, a message is sent to SO to investigate, which is not good. Let's just leave it at that, and go through the [`help/about`](http://stackoverflow.com/help) sections of SO. @Paul

Comment: You can't mouseover your own comments ;-) @Paul only from others' and it appears over to the left of a comment.

Comment: Sorry to add to this again @Fred I have realised why Im not receiving the phone field in email somehow the js is effecting it as I tested script on its own and got number in email ok was wondering if I could show you the js script Thanks Paul

Comment: Add it to your original question underneath, as an edit. @Paul I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks its added @Fred think it may be the data: section?

Comment: See my comment under your original question. @Paul